# How to achieve book-alike layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I've just got designs for android app and one thing confuses me. How to achieve that kind of layout (this is simplified version)?

[image]

I mean that book-alike borders that simulate sheets of paper in very simple way. I've tried layer list to achieve that but it seems to not working. Also that "book cover" will be gradient or image so it should be flexible somehow. What would you recommend for that kind of layout (maybe 9-patch)?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: for that you can use FrameLayout.

Comment: but it wouldn't be quite efficient with so many nested views one into another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

9-patch would work fine. Just create one in photoshop, be clever about where you place the black squares. Then, add that drawable as a background resource to your view.

Answer (score 0):

May be viewflipper can be a solution..

refer [Page Curl](https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl)

explanation: as asked by
[sanjaya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350654/sanjaya-pandey)

Simple ViewAnimator that will animate between two or more views that have been added to it. Only one child is shown at a time. If requested, can automatically flip between each child at a regular interval

link:
[ViewFlipper](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/viewflipper/android-viewflipper-example/)

Comment: Add explanation of your answer.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: thanks [kleopatra](http://stackoverflow.com/users/203657/kleopatra). I'm new to SO